# Picklist Value Limit

Tags: picklist

I am having confusion in understanding Picklist limitations. As of now, I have assumption that I can have 1K picklist values for Single picklist(not a multi picklist).

Quote from [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=picklist_limitations.htm&type=5):

> Unrestricted picklists can have up to 1,000 active values.

However, I am able to create more than 2000 active values. What I tried - created 1001 values, then deactivated them and then created 1K values again. Later I activated the 1001 values. So with this, now I have more than 2K values.

I am unsure about the final limit.

> **UPDATE**: 500 picklist limits for the multi-picklist can also be
>   breached. [*This also needs to be unrestricted*].

If anyone aware could you please let me know the **final limits for picklist values.**

Comment: You can raise a case to salesforce with your findings

Comment: Sure. Will raise!

Answer (score 2):

What you've found is a bug in the platform. Generally speaking, when the documentation says that a particular limit exists, and you find a way to work around it, then there's a bug. It is possible that this will be addressed in a future release, so you should not rely on this working in the future. Note that, as far as I'm aware, Salesforce itself is capable of handling at least 2,000 total picklist values, but it isn't meant to have more than 1,000 active values at a time. Attempting to do so may work in a particular org, but I would expect challenges when attempting to migrate this configuration to different orgs using any of the available metadata tools (Change Sets, Metadata API, DX).

Comment: Do you think there is a performance implication of having that many picklist values.?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Let's just say that when a particular limit is set in Salesforce, there's usually a performance-related reason why it's in place. I'm not sure what the reasons are (you'd probably need R&D to tell you), but I generally don't make a habit of breaking the limits to find out.

Comment: Agreed with the point of migrating the metadata. Since I need to deactivate all those, in order to add more. Tried with Multi-picklist as well, and was able to breach that limit as well. However, din't tested it for the longer limit, as deactivating the picklist values take lots of time.

Comment: @YsrShk So I found someone with an answer regarding performance, too: if you choose to do this, you will eventually suffer performance issues with the UI.